# Javascript scope different between servers

Tags: javascript, scope

My project has been running successfully for weeks during tests on the development server.  It was sent to the production server and is now failing.

It is returning this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: geoDD is not defined
```

The variable `geoDD` is a boolean, returned by a validation function.

We're not using any framework. This is happening in plain client-side js code (not node.js).  I have traced the variable and verified all the component files were migrated properly. Console panel shows all components were loaded successfully.

The dev server is a cPanel account, while production is a virtual private server running CentOS. Do different Javascript engines treat variable scope differently? Or is there something else I need to be looking for?

Comment: What is running the JS? Server-side engine? Node?

Comment: Are you talking about Node.js? or javascript on the browser

Comment: Client-side. I edited the question to specify this. Thanks for replying so quick.

Comment: That's almost impossible to answer without seeing actual code. Did not check the net panel of your console for anything that might not get loaded properly?

Comment: Yes, that was checked. I added that to the question. I'll see if I can get enough relevant code pulled together to put in a fiddle or post here.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to do with "scope differences" - and variables are *not* returned by functions (values, which can be assigned to variables, are).

Assuming the *same* code, this is caused because one of the executions assigns to a *global variable* first, before it is accessed, while the other does not. Exactly why requires inspection of the actual problematic code - one such "common" cause of such problems is asynchronous callback timings.

Of course, it could also be that *different* code is being served. Make sure the code is the same and caches are flushed.

Comment: After stepping away from the computer for a while, my question seems less logical than when I posted it. I was thinking this was a server related issue because of some other server oddities I was seeing at the time.  It has been a few weeks since I touched this code, so I'll have to dig through and see if it uses async callbacks.  This project is a refactoring of some really old code.